# As2: Creating function in a loop

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I've got problem with very simple code.

```
for(i=1;i<3;i++){
        _root.otoczenie["z"+i].onPress = function()
        {
            trace(i)
        }
    }
```

Why is every MovieClip (z1 or z2) returning "1" to the trace, and how to build it other way.

Answer (score 0):

First, this should trace "3" when you press items.

The problem is that all your functions trace the value of "i" that is the last affected by the "for".

You have to assign the value to each object for example :

```
for(var i:Number = 1; i <= 2 ; i++) {
    _root.otoczenie["z"+i].myValue = i;
    _root.otoczenie["z"+i].onPress = function () {
        trace(this.myValue);
    }
}
```

A better way would be to use the delegation and use a common function :

```
for(var i:Number = 1; i <= 2 ; i++) {
    _root.otoczenie["z"+i].myValue = i;
    _root.otoczenie["z"+i].onPress = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this,onItemPressed);
}

function onItemPressed() {
        trace(this.myValue);
}
```